# Block a steam game from myself for a period of time

Tags: steam

Is there a way  to block a certain game in my Steam lib from myself for a fixed amount of time?

I'm basically looking into a "kitchen safe for Steam games" type of solution.

Comment: Could you specify exactly why you're trying to block these games? This would strongly help us determine what advice to give you.

Comment: Remove the local files.  Then you will have to download the files again to play again.  On my connection I can only download 4-5 gigabytes/hour.

Comment: @Zibbobz I think by "kitchen safe" he means a time-lock container that helps you form good habits and can only be opened when the timer reaches zero.

Comment: If the reason is preventing procrastination, I'd just uninstall Steam itself, leaving the library intact, but (presumably) useless. Reinstalling it won't take forever, or hammer your data usage if you're on metered broadband, but it's definitely a whole Thing to download then click through the installer then the autoupdate yadda blah, hopefully enough time to make you realise you're not supposed to be doing it.

Comment: On a related note, you could try [Cold Turkey](http://getcoldturkey.com/) to prevent procrastination.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As you will have access to the account you will pretty much always have easy access to the game, The easiest ways to do it on your own without any third party scripts etc are to:

- Delete the game; without local content you won't be able to play it.  You can always download it again at your leisure.  You can then selected Installed from drop down menu under Games to only show your installed games, I actually forget about a lot of games I have because of this (although not on purpose).
- Ask Steam Support to permanently delete the game from your library,
  however this will mean you will lose it forever unless you
  repurchase it (or add it again if it's F2P).  Not an ideal choice for
  a temporary measure.
- When there is a game update allow it to download a small %, then
  pause the download.  Change your settings to stop automatic
  updates for that game; the option should be in that game's Properties
  on Steam.  You can also set all other games (which is the case to
  Default) to not allow background downloads, so that it won't update
  that way when you're playing something else.  The benefit here is
  that you can't play the game until the update is complete, the
  downside is you need to wait for an update.  If it's Payday 2 then
  you'll have DLC released every 2 days, so that won't be long (joke!
  ;) ).
- Use Steam Family View - With Family View you can restrict content,
  pretty much like a parental lock (which is kind of what it is).  The
  only drawback here is that you know the PIN code so could easily
  bypass it, and if you forgot the PIN code you'll need to contact
  Steam Support to access restricted material!  For details on Family
  View see here:
  https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5149-EOPC-9918
- Forget, or deliberately don't use, your login details for Steam.  If
  you can't access the client then you won't have access to the game. 
  The downside here is that means you don't have the client for *any*
  games.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing why there was a downvote with no comment, especially after I posted this here on the OPs request.

Comment: To help OP hide his password effectively, a password manager (e.g. Keepassx) might be useful. You can generate very long, pseudo-random passwords impossible to remember. I'm curious about which game is it.

Comment: @MattR I did comment but the nice admins deleted my comment. So much for "please explain the downvotes"…

Comment: @Lohoris OK well I didn't see it.  Feel free to post it again, if it's constructive.

Comment: @MattR it wasn't exactly "constructive", but at least it was an explanation. No intention to re-write stuff that is going to be deleted anyway. The sooner they come back to their senses, the better. This "let's delete stuff" mania is ruining this entire network…

Comment: @Lohoris well if it wasn't constructive I don't see why there is an issue with it being deleted?  My answer was given originally as a comment, and the OP asked for it to be put as an answer (I then expanded on it).  So if you had no constructive feedback for your downvote...

Comment: @MattR the site pop-ups a suggestion "please explain your downvote" when you downvote, and I did just that…

Comment: @Lohoris OK well, again, I haven't seen that feedback as to why, you don't want to say why, and as such there is no point in the continuation of this discussion.  I asked for feedback about the downvote as it may have helped me understand how I could have made my answer better, you don't seem to want to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23595/discussion-between-mattr-and-lohoris).

Answer (score 23):

You can right click on a game in your library and select "Set Categories".  When you do this, there is a "Hide this game in my library" check box.

If you then want to see the hidden games (to unhide them), click on the filter next to the search box in your library screen (the one where you can choose "Games"/"Installed"/"Recent" etc)

Comment: Came here to suggest this, as I've only recently discovered I can do it. This doesn't re-show it at a scheduled date, but it does make it easy to ignore & forget a game.

Answer (score 8):

It's silly but you could encrypt the file system of that game, give the encryption key to a friend/your mum and tell them to not give it back to you until 'x'; be that you've done your homework or whatever you're trying to get yourself to do.

A better idea would be to look into how to increase yourself control.

Comment: Or write the encryption key down and lock it in a kitchen safe. :-)

Comment: or mail it to yourself.  No game until it comes back in your mailbox..

Comment: Or [time-lock encryption](http://www.gwern.net/Self-decrypting%20files)!

Answer (score 2):

You could always give your login details to somebody you trust such as a family member, who can then change them and agree a time when you can have them back.

I know somebody who did this and it worked for them, it is the best way to avoid temptation.

Answer (score -1):

Just make it not possible to play a game within X amount of time. If you want to restrict yourself to play, the only possible option is to let it cost time to play a game (like installing in, or install steam, install game) etc. In this time you can rethink more than once to think of your choice and stop the install procedure.

If you really want to stop play a game and make it impossible, just install an old VGA-card in your computer and store it in your closet. Now it takes a lot of time to play your game (Okay, maybe Tetris or SimCity 1.) :)

Answer (score -3):

Step 1: Uninstall the game.

Step 2: Find out how much free space the game requires.

Step 3: Install other software (or download media) until the free space on you HDD is less then the amount needed to reinstall the game.

This won't work very well if you have a HUGE HDD or if the game is tiny. However you could also uninstall steam, partition your hard drive with a "just big enough" partition and install steam on that partition...

Comment: That is just plain silly.

Comment: Not really. No sillier than having a friend/roommate change your credentials, or encrypting important files or any of the other answers. @Progo wants to limit access to a game, and when just deciding not to do a thing isn't sufficient, you need to put some serious friction between yourself and starting again. Difficulty installing a game just might be sufficient to keep them away.

Comment: Filling the filesystem is overly complicated, would decrease performance, requires filling it with somewhat valuable files and assumes that he hasn't other external memories. What if he has 4 TB worth of external storage? Deleting the game files, or staying away from steam by hiding the pass are way more cost-efficient methods.

Comment: It's silly because it's asking to install apparently unwanted software or media (since presumably if this software or media was desired, it would already be on the system). Where is someone supposed to find potentially gigabytes of "other software"? It introduces more problems than it solves.

Comment: Assuming the OP is trying to not spend too much time playing the game, the time to implement this solution might end up being *longer*.