# How can I block a Steam game from ever being installed on my PC?

Tags: steam, brawlhalla

Sometimes my friends want us to play brawlhalla. I then think that's a good idea because sometimes it's fun. But every time I play it I'm reminded by just how insanely angry I get and just how much I hate this game. Every time I play ranked solo, I rage like I have never done and it's crazy, I feel like a complete savage afterwards when I get down to Earth. I never get this angry playing any video games, normally I'm chill and enjoy. But this one game seriously drives me nuts when I play it.

So I always end up deleting it, but then a few months later, I install it for another round and forget just how badly I hated this game, then I'm reminded again.

So now I want a way to prevent this game from ever being installed on my desktop ever again. I could get some self control and stop myself, but it's happened like 3-4 times now that I install thinking it will be fun with my friends, but it ends up being agonizing. So to really leave this game for good and NEVER play it again, I want to make it IMPOSSIBLE to download. So when in 3-12 months, I sit down with optimism, that I would then get quickly reminded, just how unhealthy this game is for me.

So is there any way to make it IMPOSSIBLE to download this specific game on my local machine or Steam account?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Block a steam game from myself for a period of time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/218688/block-a-steam-game-from-myself-for-a-period-of-time)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can permanently remove the game from your account, making it forever unplayable (unless you purchase it again).

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246442/2578) has the full steps, plus pictures.

> - Log into Steam Support
> - Select Games, Software, etc.,
> - Select the game from the search function that shows up
> - Select the option: I want to permanently remove this game from my account.
> - Select the option: Ok, remove the listed games from my account permanently.

Comment: Technically, this doesn't make it _impossible_ since you can still purchase it again, and seeing how the OP **really** seems to want it to be impossible, I'm not sure if this will be good enough.

Comment: Brawlhalla is free to play, so OP wouldn't need to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

No, as anything that's done to prevent it (quarantine the executable, remove the license from your account, block internet access with firewall, change permissions so you can't run it, tag the game in Steam as "DO NOT PLAY", etc) can be reverted.

It's up to you to "DARE to say no" to games that are toxic to you.

Comment: This is true in a technical sense, but it doesn't really answer the question, as at some point there will be enough of an atypical speed bump that the OP will surely realize "Wait, there's a reason I'm not playing this game ..."

Comment: Exactly. OP has to make the choice to say no to playing the game as anything reasonable done to prevent installation can be reverted when they have the itch to play. Technology can not fix this issue, as it's purely psychological. Fear of missing out, sunken cost fallacy, etc. Moving Rocket League to a folder called BS on PS4 hasn't stopped me, nor did uninstalling a couple months ago. Projecting the blame onto the technology doesn't do anything but give a scapegoat for bad decisions.